# How to hide properties on Azure Mobile Service responses?

Tags: azure-mobile-services, dto, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a Mobile Service with Model classes and DTO classes. I mapped these using Fluent API and got it to work to perform CRUD operations, but I have a problem with the JSON responses returned in some instances.

Take for example a User entity with user name and password. To register a user I have my PostUserDTO method like this:

```
    // POST tables/UserDTO
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostUserDTO(UserDTO item)
    {
        string hashString = PasswordHash.CreateHash(item.Password);
        item.Password = hashString;
        UserDTO current = await InsertAsync(item);
        current.Password = "";
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }
```

On the method I read the password property sent from the client and then proceed to hash it with a salt, replace the value in the object sent and save it to the database, then I proceed to empty the password so the hashed result isn't returned.

In this case the best practice would be to omit the password property from the response, this also should happen when retrieving all of the users in the table, I only want to return specific information, some information generated by my server should stay out from the response.

How can I select or alter the information from the responses? Do I have to create other DTOs for every kind of response I desire?

Comment: You should read this article [Get started with custom authentication](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/), because I think you are going in the right way...